# Does the server send response only when its HTTP 200?

Tags: java, http

im writing a java application that sends a post request to a server and expect a json from the server. Now when i need to get the response from the server do i only need to get it from the inputStream when the http code is 200 (HTTP OK) or is there any other cases ? , example :

```
//...
if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// only here try to get the response 
}
//...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the server is implemented. Check the API, if the server has one. If it's internal, ask your server guy.

Generally speaking, if your response code is either 2xx or 3xx, I would check the response anyway...

Comment: 201, 202, 203, 204 are often used for RESTful API calls of various sorts … likewise, 401, 402, or 403 might be returned from some API's for authentication failures …

Frankly, I would try to parse anything that comes back that even *smells* like JSON, in cases like this.

Comment: @BRPocock +1, I agree. Parse Everything that comes back. If it's an error or something, log it. If it's JSON, parse it. If nothing comes back, then you've just lost a nanosecond checking.

Comment: The "good guys" will at least give you a relatively informative error message for your end-user … on a good day :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the server your communicating with is following the spec then either 200 or 201 responses are valid to contain an entity. A 204 response is successful but has no data in the response.

See section 9.5 here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5 for details of acceptable responses to a POST. Extract below:

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
>   that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
>   (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
>   or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.
>
> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to consider:

1. All 2xx codes denote success of some sort. But depending on the exact code, your reading code might be different. (204 for example means success but no content.)
2. There are redirecting codes (3xx). These are usually automatically followed by the http client library but you can also set them not to, in which case you need to have custom code that handles these cases.
3. There can be valuable information returned in the stream even if you get a code that denotes an error. Whether you want to process it depends on your exact needs.

Comment: so lets say i didnt get HTTP_OK (due to problem in my json format for example), can the server still send me a custom response?

Comment: @Jimmy It depends on the server. I've seen webservices return a well-formatted error message along with code 500. Generally I think you should always read the response, and then decide what to do with it depending on the response code.